# rm succeed but it prints out rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux

I am building a tiny shell in linux. After I run `ls -la /tmp > output`, I can view the output by using `cat`. If I try to `rm` output, the removal succeeds but shows `rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory.`

Here is my code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[LINESZ + 2];
    cmd_string C;
    initialize(&C);

    while (1) {
        // Free up allocated memory, if any
        FREE_ALLOCATED_MEMORY(C);

        // Let's print the shell prompt
        printf("tinyshell> ");

        // read a line (i.e., input string) from stdin
        if (fgets(line, LINESZ, stdin) == NULL) {
            return 0; // reached EOF (end-of-file), so we can safely terminate
        }
        parse_cmd_string(line, &C);

        unsigned char r = process_builtin_commands(&C);
        if (r == 1)
            continue; 

        int fc = fork();
        if (fc < 0) {
            PRINT_ERROR_SYSCALL("fork");
            return 1;
        } else
        if (fc == 0) {
            char *myargs[strlen(*C.args) + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(*C.args); i++) {
                myargs[i] = C.args[i];
            }
            myargs[strlen(*C.args) + 1] = NULL;
            if (execvp(myargs[0], myargs) < 0) {
                PRINT_ERROR_SYSCALL("execvp");
            }

            FREE_ALLOCATED_MEMORY(C);
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this all your code?

Comment: A good place to start in determining whether you're providing a [mcve] others can use to see the problem themselves and test a fix is trying to reproduce the same bug on an online interpreter like http://ideone.com/

Comment: @KamilCuk there are more but i dont think stackoverflow post too long code. Sorry

Comment: Right -- we don't want *all* your code, but the *shortest possible working code* someone else can see the problem with, without making any changes. Thus, by changing that sample, people can test their answers.

Comment: ...without a `main()`, any includes, etc., this is surely not working code, thus it also can't be shortest-possible-working-code that demonstrates an issue.

Comment: `cmd_string C;` <<-- what is this?

Comment: `myargs[strlen(*C.args) + 1] = NULL` is out of bounds for `myargs`. The last index is `strlen(*C.args)`. But... Why the count of arguments is equal to length of some string? What a strange function `parse_cmd_string` must be. I do not believe you understand what `strlen` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is inconsistent:

- the number of elements in the array `myargs` is 1 plus the length of the first argument string, presumably the name of the command. This seems incorrect.
- you assign `strlen(C.args[0])` string pointers from the array `C.args[]`. Again, this seems incorrect and may have undefined behavior if this array is defined with fewer elements.
- you attempt to set a `NULL` pointer terminator at the end of the array with `myargs[strlen(*C.args)+1] = NULL;`, but you actually set the element **after** the end of the array, which has undefined behavior.

You are playing with fire running the `rm` command with potentially random arguments this way. You are lucky no useful file was removed before this bizarre diagnostic message, probably caused by an empty string argument at the end of the array.

As *Keith Thomson* commented, if you want to test a shell that might not work correctly, use something like `echo` rather than `rm`.

Comment: If you want to test a shell that might not work correctly, use something like `echo` rather than `rm`.

Comment: Yea. i found out there is out of index problem. thanks